# joomla 1.7 query format

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.7

I've run into a lot of posts in various forums showing a new format for building Joomla queries within components and apps that look object-oriented--

http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Platform/Database/JDatabaseQuery.html

```
$query->select('*');
$query->from('table1');
$query->from('table2');
$query->leftJoin('table3 ON my_field = my_other_field');
```

However, the docs are thin on examples (maybe should say nonexistent!)

Can anyone suggest a resource showing the use of these new classes/methods in action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been up a week with no input-- so far here's the best resource I've found on the new syntax: http://www.theartofjoomla.com/home/9-developer/135-database-upgrades-in-joomla-16.html